# How can I access Certificate ExtendedProperties using powershell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, capicom

If you open the properties window of a certificate in the certificate manager in windows you will see both a friendlyname and description field.  I'm trying to get to the description field programatically via powershell.

When accessing the certificates via powershell's certificate provider cert: you get an object that only exposes the FriendlyName as Name.

As far as I can tell, this is all a wrapper to the CAPICOM APIs.  Neither the description or the get_extendedproperties method are exposed.

How can I access the description field problematically via powershell?  Please note that I tried to simply do

```
$store = new-object -com "CAPICOM.Store"
```

to use the CAPICOM api directly ala [This Link](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/2006-04/msg00081.html), but I get a 80040154 error on my 64bit Win2K8 box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open x86 Powershell instead of x64. This should get you started:

```
$store = new-object -com "CAPICOM.Store"
$store.Open(2, "CA", 1)
$store | fl *
$store.Certificates
$store.Certificates | %{ $_.display() }
$store.Certificates | %{ $_.extendedproperties() }
```

Comment: Great, that worked and gets me closer to solving the problem.  I'll do some researching before asking about the 64 bit version of CAPICOM.